# create oracle sql cursor inside procedure ERROR

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I created a procedure for calculating salary of employees by considering shift table data
my shift table is ,

```
CREATE TABLE SHIFT
        (SHIFT_ID NUMBER(4),
        SHIFT_DATE DATE,
        CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER(4),
        SERVICE_ID NUMBER(4),
        EMPLOYEE_ID  NUMBER(4),
        SHIFT_CHARGE FLOAT(10), 
        PRIMARY KEY(SHIFT_ID)
        );
```

my procedure is,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CAL_SALLARY
AS
CURSOR SHIFT_CURSOR IS SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,SUM(SHIFT_CHARGE) AS SALARY FROM SHIFT GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID;
BEGIN
    OPEN SHIFT_CURSOR;
    LOOP
        FETCH SHIFT_CURSOR INTO SHIFT_REC;
        EXIT WHEN SHIFT_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYYE ID : '||SHIFT_REC.EMPLOYEE_ID||' SALARY : '||SHIFT_REC.SALARY);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE SHIFT_CURSOR; 
END;
/
```

But when I try to run this procedure in SQL plus, it says compilation fails. I count found what's the issue.
 please anyone help me.

Comment: As a minor side note: salary is spelled with a single "L".

Answer (score 2):

You *forgot* to declare cursor variable (see line #7):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CAL_SALLARY
  2  AS
  3  CURSOR SHIFT_CURSOR IS
  4    SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, SUM(SHIFT_CHARGE) AS SALARY
  5    FROM SHIFT GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID;
  6
  7    shift_Rec shift_cursor%rowtype;
  8  BEGIN
  9      OPEN SHIFT_CURSOR;
 10      LOOP
 11          FETCH SHIFT_CURSOR INTO SHIFT_REC;
 12          EXIT WHEN SHIFT_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;
 13          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYYE ID : '||SHIFT_REC.EMPLOYEE_ID
 14                                ||' SALARY : '||SHIFT_REC.SALARY);
 15      END LOOP;
 16      CLOSE SHIFT_CURSOR;
 17  END;
 18  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

---

A simpler option is cursor FOR loop; Oracle does most of *dirty* job for you (e.g. declaring cursor variable, opening and closing cursor, exiting the loop):

```
SQL> create or replace procedure cal_sallary as
  2  begin
  3    for shift_rec in (select employee_id, sum(shift_charge) as salary
  4                      from shift
  5                      group by employee_id
  6                     )
  7    loop
  8      dbms_output.put_line('EMPLOYYE ID : '||shift_rec.employee_id
  9                           ||' SALARY : '||shift_rec.salary);
 10    end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```